# Are there any Vietnamese Chu Nom/Han Nom IMEs for Linux (preferably for fcitx)?

Tags: fcitx

I was wondering if there are any Vietnamese Chu Nom/Han Nom IMEs out there for Linux. I've seen a couple for Windows but I have yet to see any for Linux yet in my searching so far.

So my question is, are there any Chu Nom/Han Nom IMEs for Ubuntu, preferably for fcitx? I'm using fcitx-unikey to type regular Vietnamese right now on my machine but I was wondering if there were any packages or the like that facilitates the typing of Chu Nom/Han Nom on Linux.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [Rime](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ibus-rime), and use [schemas](https://www.hannom-rcv.org/) provided by 委班復生漢喃越南 Ủy ban Phục sinh Hán Nôm Việt Nam. This allows you to type chữ Nôm by using [Telex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telex_(input_method)).

> 些 trăm năm trong cõi người ta would be "trawm nawm trong coix nguwowif ta"

The schemas made by Ủy ban Phục sinh Hán Nôm Việt Nam contains Chinese characters and their variants, alongside Nôm characters. You can type any character as long you  how to spell them in Vietnamese.

> 我是中國人 ngã thị trung quốc nhân would be "ngax thij trung quoocs nhaan"

Answer (score 1):

You can type Chữ Nôm using Cangjie5 Chinese input.

Examples using http://chinesecj.com/ime/cj5.php (cutt.ly/oiar):

1. 喃 (jnjnd rjbj)
2. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters#/media/File:Tale_of_Kieu_parallel_text.svg

揆些才命窖恄饒
(madd jboq yuob2 qnok aio ypmm jdjnd dh jdjnd omrl jchgr wlk pgr oiggu)

You can download http://chinesecj.com/ime/cj5.php (cutt.ly/oiar) and use the IME offline, too.

fcitx-table-cangjie5 should contain all these characters, but I couldn't type  with it.

(Generally, linux cangjie inplementations seem to lack some rare variants. But, of the linux implementations, fcitx seems to be most complete.)

Cangjie5, generally, can type around 70000+ characters including:

1. Traditional Chinese characters
2. Simplified Chinese characters
3. Cantonese characters
4. Ancient / rare variants
5. Japanese variants and kana
6. And, it seems, Chữ Nôm, though I've not used it for that until just now.

Once you learn the basic rules, you can type any character your can visualize or see, quickly and accurately.

With fcitx, you can also use "?" if you're unsure of part of a code, too. For instance, 喃 (rjbj) could be searched for using "rj??".

If you're wanting to type Vietnamese and get Chữ Nôm in return, I'm not sure how to set that up. But I do know you can setup a lot of custom user phrases in fcitx.

Anyway, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fcitx-m17n, fcitx5-m17n or ibus-m17n